# Finding a text node #text in Selenium Python

Tags: python, html, selenium

I have the following HTML

```
<div class="detailSection">
            <span>Authorized Person(s) Detail</span>
            <span>
                     <b>Name &amp; Address</b>
            </span>
            <br>
            <br>
            <span>Title&nbsp;MGR</span>
            <br>
            <br>
            "
            EYN, KHASHY    "   
            <span>

               <div>
               100 Wall Street<br>
               NEW YORK, NY 10005<br>
               </div>
    
            </span>
            <br>
            </div>
```

I would like to extract the EYN, KHASHY portion of the HTML. My Chrome developer tools tells me this is a #text node(?) and I think that is why it is not working with my current code. Although I am not familiar with #text nodes at all but it seems distinct from the HTML.

Currently my code selects all children elements of the `<div>` which is parent to the #text. As follows:

```
 persons = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="maincontent"]/div[2]/div[6]')
        all_children = persons.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*")
        for child in all_children:
            li_person.append(child.text)
            print(child.text)
```

This gives me all the text except the EYN, KHASHY. Probably because all other text is part of a certain element as Chrome dev tools tell me when I hover over. The #text "EYN, KHASHY" returns as blank.

How can I select this node and extract this information?

Comment: If "persons" is the parent `<div>` block, then what you want is `persons.text`.  That text is not in a child tag, it is the text of that tag.

Comment: Omg I can't believe I overlooked that. Thank you. Please post as an answer so I may mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "persons" is the parent `<div>` block, then what you want is `persons.text`. That text is not in a child tag, it is the text of that tag